# CPLEX - Optimization - Minimize production cost by period: Error: Model is non-convex

Tags: optimization, cplex, docplex

I'm trying to create an optimization model using CPLEX.

My problem is:

I have demand, production capacity (by machine by day), and production cost (by machine by day) to produce the products.
Some machines have diferent cost and production capacity to produce same product.

I am trying to build an optimization model that produces the demand products while minimizing the cost of production.

With the below code, I'm getting the error
**Error: Model is non-convex**

```
import pandas as pd
dmd =  {
        'TONS_BY_MONTH': {'PRODUCT_A': 27283.781, 'PRODUCT_B': 119.477, 'PRODUCT_C': 4651.003}
    }
df_demanda = pd.DataFrame(dmd)
df_demanda

custo = {
     'MC05': {'PRODUCT_A': 1368, 'PRODUCT_B': 1368, 'PRODUCT_C': 1368},
     'MC06': {'PRODUCT_A': 1435, 'PRODUCT_B': 1435, 'PRODUCT_C': 1427},
     'MC07': {'PRODUCT_A': 1189, 'PRODUCT_B': 1207, 'PRODUCT_C': 0},
     'MC08': {'PRODUCT_A': 1221, 'PRODUCT_B': 1209, 'PRODUCT_C': 0},
     'MC09': {'PRODUCT_A': 1905, 'PRODUCT_B': 1907, 'PRODUCT_C': 1965}
     } 

df_custo = pd.DataFrame(custo)
df_custo

produtos = ['PRODUCT_A', 'PRODUCT_B', 'PRODUCT_C']
maquinas = ['MC05','MC06','MC07','MC08','MC09']
dias = list(range(1,30))

capacidade = {
    'MC05': {'PRODUCT_A': 371, 'PRODUCT_B': 371, 'PRODUCT_C': 427},
    'MC06': {'PRODUCT_A': 396, 'PRODUCT_B': 396, 'PRODUCT_C': 435},
    'MC07': {'PRODUCT_A': 547, 'PRODUCT_B': 571, 'PRODUCT_C': 0},
    'MC08': {'PRODUCT_A': 476, 'PRODUCT_B': 497, 'PRODUCT_C': 0},
    'MC09': {'PRODUCT_A': 657, 'PRODUCT_B': 692, 'PRODUCT_C': 790}
    }
df_capacidade = pd.DataFrame(capacidade)
df_capacidade

from docplex.mp.model import Model
mdl = Model(name="DEMANDA_BY_DAY")



x  = {(i,j):
      mdl.continuous_var(name="PRODUCAO_{0}_{1}".format(i,j)) for i in produtos for j in maquinas }


DIAS  = {(d):
         mdl.binary_var(name="DIA_{0}".format(d)) for d in dias}

mdl.minimize(mdl.sum([ DIAS[d] * (df_custo.loc[i,j] * x[(i,j)]) for d in dias for i in produtos for j in maquinas]))



for i in produtos:
             mdl.add_constraint( mdl.sum([x[(i,j)] * DIAS[d] for d in DIAS  for j in maquinas ]) == df_demanda.loc[i,'TONS_BY_MONTH'])

for i in produtos:
             mdl.add_constraint(  mdl.sum([x[(i,j)] * DIAS[d]  for d in DIAS for j in maquinas ]) <= mdl.sum([df_capacidade.loc[i,s] for s in maquinas]))
        
        
mdl.solve(log_output=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model contains constraints with sums of terms of the form x_i * y_+i.
Such constraints are not convex, basically any quadratic product of two different variables X *Y is non-convex.
CPLEX does not yet solve non-convex QCPs, so you need to reformulate your problem without these products. I see two possible ways:

- either extend the X variable matrix (BTW, you can probably use Model.continuous_var_matrix to simplify) with one extra dimension for days, and you have one variable per triple (product, machine, day)
- also check indicator constraint: an indicator constraint link dynamically the value of a binary variable and a linear constraint. IN other terms, if during the search for a solution, the binary variable becomes 1 (or 0) then some linear constraint is enforced, otherwise it is undefined whether it is true or false.

For example, the following code

```
mdl.add_indicator(dias[0], x[1,2] ==0, active_value=0)
```

states that if the final value of the binary variables `dias[0]` is 0 (the `active_value`), then the constraint `x[1,2]==0` becomes true.

Note that this works one-way: the value of the binary variable influences the status of the constraint, but not the other way round.

Let me know if you have questions on the reformulation of the model.

Comment: Hi Philippe,
Thank's for your time.
I understood that I need to eliminate the product of two different variables.
But I'm not sure how can I buid the objective and constraints without this. 

I will post the version using your suggestion with one extra dimension for days. 

I will appretiate any comments.

Comment: Trying the suggestion from @philippe-couronne eliminate the product of two different variables using extra dimension for days:

Using the code below I'm getting the Infeasibility response, because the model was unable to find the match value of demand.

I'm doing this right?

Comment: x  = {(i,j, d):
           mdl.continuous_var(name="PRODUCAO_{0}_{1}_{2}".format(i,j,d)) for i in produtos for j in maquinas for d in dias}

## OBJECTIVE: min cost of production x days
mdl.minimize(
    mdl.sum([ (df_custo.loc[i,j] * d) * x[(i,j,d)] for i in produtos for j in maquinas for d in dias])
)


## CONSTRAINT: demand for product
for i in produtos:
      mdl.add_constraint( mdl.sum([x[(i,j,d)] for j in maquinas for d in dias]) == df_demanda.loc[i,'TONS_BY_MONTH'])

Comment: ## CONSTRAINT 2: cost of product
for i in produtos:
     for j in maquinas:
            for d in dias:
                mdl.add_constraint(mdl.sum([x[(i,j,d)] ]) == df_custo.loc[i,j] *d)
                
mdl.solve(log_output=True)

Comment: I suggest you start by providing the spec of the problem, as text, before discussing implementations.

Comment: Hi, Sure,
I am trying to build an optimization model that produces the products in demand while minimizing the cost of production. Note the description above:
Ex: To produce 27k Product A:
I need to allocate 10 days machineMC05 + 3 days machineMC06 ... so on
Thanks

Comment: Sorry , one point remains unclear to me, the management of days (DIAS): where do you specify how many days you run each machine? and how are days modeled: as a resource limited to 30 or do you want to schedule production activities (start, end, duration)? I hope not, as this would make the model a scheduling problem, much more complex.

Comment: Hi,
I believe the easy way is to set the variable days(DIAS) as a no limited resource- any value betwen 1 and 30 - to simplicity. I hope the model can return how many days (continuous variable) I need to produce each demand.Ex:   PRODUCAO_PRODUCT_A_MC05_9=3,32 days.  
I'm trying do that by product df_custo.loc[i,j] * d on Objective and constraint. 
Thanks.